# mariadb の 「character_set_server」がutf8にならない

Tags: mariadb

mariadbの「character_set_server」をutf8に設定すべく、DB内で以下のコマンドを打ちました。

```
> set character_set_server=utf8;
> show variables like 'char%';
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

しかしながら、一度exitしたのち、再度確認したところ、
 「character_set_server」は「latin1」となってしまいます。

また、「/etc/myconf.d」の[mysqld]内に、「character-set-server=utf8」を記載していますが、DB内の文字コードを確認したところ、「character_set_server」が「latin1」となります。

原因とその解消方法を教えていただきたく、質問させていただきます。

◆ 追記
該当テーブルの文字コードを確認した結果は以下の通りです。

```
> show create table [テーブル名]
CREATE TABLE `[テーブル名]` (
  // カラムのため、記載省略
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. mysql5.6の話ですが、SET文はデフォルトではセッションでのみ有効なようです。

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/ja/set-statement.html

2. utf8は旧型式です。utf8mb4を使用しましょう。
   utf8では日本語第三水準第四水準に登場するutf8時に4Byteになる約400漢字が非対応です。

character-set-server=utf8mb4
default-character-set=utf8mb4

3. cnfファイルの再読み込みには、mariadbを再起動する必要がありそうです。
   複数回設定している場合は、最後の設定が有効になるので注意しましょう。
   !includedir /etc/my.cnf.dなど記述されている場合は、その下も確認する必要があります。

systemctl restart mariadb.service